# Update winform from windows service

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, service

We have design one winform application in C# 3.5, which connect to external Ethernet device and communicate with them after every specific interval. The overall flow is mentioned below

- Winform fetches all the external Ethernet devices details (such as their   ip address, name, and location) and Load the details in objectlistview.
- in background, new  thread get initialized and connect to external Ethernet device one after another and some data communication happen.
- The said thread update the status bar while connecting to such external devices and update the objectlistview along with few other gui controls once the communication complete with each device one after another.

Now I want to migrate the above said background thread operation to windows service which will connect and communicate with external Ethernet devices and update the GUI every time.

Everything related to connection and communication i can handle in service But i am confused how I will be able to update the GUI such as list view and status bar from service, so that end user should able to understand current status of system

One way i think is service will update the communication result in database and GUI application will fetch the said details from db to update the status. 
But is there any other way apart from this, Any inputs are greatly appreciated for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Polling is by far the easiest option, and depending on the requirements could be sufficient. Otherwise look at something like SignalR for near-realtime updates.

Comment: You will have to set a set of protocol. Previously, I've done it using polling but I dealt with TCP. You will have to create GUI according to the data you receive from ethernet by referring to your protocol.